# How to disable devtools on electron.lauch() in playwright end-to-end testing

Tags: electron, playwright

Playwright electronApp.firstWindow() sometimes returned the DevTools window and sometimes the actual main window.

If the DevTools window is returned, the test waits indefinitely for the selector.

Error: expect(received).toContain(expected) // indexOf

```
Expected substring: "ecommerce"
Received string:    "DevTools"

  23 |   });
  24 |   test('App launches and quits', async () => {
> 25 |     await expect(await page.title()).toContain('ecommerce');
     |                                      ^
  26 |   });
```